# How to use 'toHaveClass' to match a substring in Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

There's an element to which I'm giving a class `success`. But React-Mui appends a text to it on DoM, say, something like `mui-AbcXYZ-success`. So when I'm doing this

`expect( getByTestId('thirdCheck')).toHaveClass("success")`

I don't get this test passing as it expects the complete name `mui-AbcXYZ-success`. I’m getting this passed only when I provide the exact name (wirh hyphenated text and random number that mui adds)

How do I test that?

I tried doing the following without reasult:
`expect( getByTestId('thirdCheck')).toHaveClass(/success/)`

I also tried applying  `.className` or `.classList` but that doesn’t give me the list of classes on the element.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After hours of frustrations, this is how I did and if any one has a better solution, feel free to post. I shall accept it.

```
      let classes = getByTestId('thirdCheck').getAttribute('class'); //returns something like "Mui-root mui-AbcXYZ-success"
        classes=classes.split(' ')[1].split('-'); //first split is to split on the basis of spaces and the second one to do on the bases of hyphen
        expect(classes.includes('success'));
```

Looks like a bit verbose for a trivial-looing thing. But that's how did.

**UPDATE:**

@Fyodor has a great point in the comment.
We can simply do this as follows:

`expect(getByTestId('thirdCheck').getAttribute('class')).toMatch(/success/gi)`

Comment: Awesome solution! If you don't care about exact class relative position among other classes, you can do `expect(getByTestId('thirdCheck').getAttribute('class')).toMatch(/success/gi)`

Comment: @Fyodor Your comment is the better answer!

Answer (score 11):

With CSS-in-JS, classNames will sometimes get appended with generic identifiers. So it is nice to have a quick way of verifying your custom class is on an element. This is a loose one line approach for verifying the substring of a custom class without regex.

Note: It does not ignore casing. If you need that, then the answer with toMatch is a better solution for you.

```
expect(yourSelectedElement.getAttribute("class")).toContain("yourClassSubstring");
```

Answer (score 1):

expect(yourSelectedElement.classList).toContain("yourClassSubstring");

Comment: Your answer seems correct, but you got to explain it and apply some format.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).